Alire macOS Sonoma GTKAda "gtk.ads" not found when compiling a simple "Hello, World!" program
I am having trouble compiling and running a simple GTKAda "Hello, World!" program on a macOS Sonoma M3 Mac. I'm using "alr-6768bdb" from GitHub it's the 11, December 2023 beta version of Alire 2.0 for aarch64 Macs. In GNAT Studio when compiling, I get: "gtk.ads" not found. I'm not sure where to go from here.

I’ve uploaded a release of alr 2.0.1 -- I don’t think this can be the reason for your GNAT Studio problem, though.
I’ll assume you already have a directory my_hello/ containing your project file, named my_hello.gpr, set up to generate an executable bin/my_hello (it’s easier if the names match).
Configure alr to open GNAT Studio on the current crate’s project file:
alr settings --set editor.cmd 'open -n -a gnatstudio --args ${GPR_FILE}'

Then, set up a crate for your project:

in my_hello/, alr init --bin --in-place --no-skel my_hello
alr with gtkada

Now, alr edit should run GNAT Studio with my_hello.gpr.

I'm getting "glib.h" not found. I am using a solution in my .zprofile that you gave me one time, but still getting the glib.h error:
eval $(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/include
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/include
export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/lib

alr 2.0 defines those paths for you. brew info glib says I have 2.80.0 installed; looking at the gtkada_shared.gpr generated when alr built gtkada, in (wait for it!) ~/.local/share/alire/builds/gtkada_24.0.0_80c56171/*, I see that some way down Gtk_Include includes "-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/glib/2.80.0/include", under which there’s glib-2.0/glib.h.

I have everything installed and set, but I still can't get it to find glib.h  My version is 2,80_2

I'm probably doing something wrong, but when I run the exact command you provided to create the crate and run "alr edit" it says that my_hello.gpr doesn't exist.

Well, it seems like it has started to work, but unfortunately I'm not 100 percent sure why. I'm not getting the "gtk.ads" error anymore, the "glib.h" error has stopped as well. I am using a MacBook M3 with Sonoma, the Alire aarch64 version 2.0.1, and the latest macOS GNAT Studio. I know this is not an answer, I apologize and I thank you very much for your help!

Yes, one always likes to understand why
